# How to apply .skin file in DotNetNuke project

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I am new to DotNetNuke. My question is how to apply the skin file to the control of the page.

I have the Test.Skin file, I know how to apply that in .NET, but not familiar with the DotNetNuke standard. And Also Where to Locate or Put this Test.Skin File in DotNetNuke Project

Answer (score 1):

DotNetNuke skinning does not use the .skin file process.  DotNetNuke skins are created using HTML/CSS and are found in the various /portals/_default/skins folder.